# offline package install going old-school help

Tags: software-installation

i have to download packages from the address https://packages.ubuntu.com on an online windows pc.
i want to copy them to an external usb drive and transfer them to an offline ubuntu studio pc and install them manually on the offline pc. do i just look for each package that i need from that web site's listings, download them all, go to each of the dependancy pages listed for each one by one and download each of them until i get 'em all from the whole list tree? i am happy to do this to get all the stuff i want on the offline pc if i have to. i don't think it would even take that long at all. complete back-ups are very important for me. any workflow suggestions or pointers, tips or anything to watch out for? thank you all for the help.

Comment: This is a valid method. Download packages with dependencies.

Comment: You may find the `--print-uris` option of `apt` / `apt-get` useful for generating the dependency list - see for example [Getting .deb package dependencies for an offline Ubuntu computer through Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219828/getting-deb-package-dependencies-for-an-offline-ubuntu-computer-through-windows/219837)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: i want to mark the post from Pilot6 (posted on Feb 18 at 21:59) as the answer but i do not understand how to do this. i read through the support center entries but i cannot find the option to do this. i apologize. this is my first forum membership.